# Frapper au visage / frapper le visage / frapper en plein visage / frapper sur le visage / frapper dans le visage

Tags: sens, expressions

Bonjour,

> Frapper **au** visage.
>
> Frapper **le** visage.
>
> Frapper **en** plein visage.
>
> Frapper **sur** le visage.
>
> Frapper **dans** le visage.

Il y a beaucoup plus d'exemples contenant les deux premières expressions, mais je pense que les deux dernières doivent aussi être possibles. Est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre ces cinq tours ? Je pense que non, mis à part le deuxième peut-être, *frapper **le** visage contre le mur*. J'ai aussi l'impression que dans *frapper **dans** le visage* et *frapper **le** visage*, l'action est plus violente.

Answer (score 1):

Les quatre premières formes sont idiomatiques, la cinquième beaucoup moins à mon avis.

Tu as déjà montré qu'elles ne sont pas forcément interchangeables puisque *contre le mur* impose la deuxième.

*Au visage* est plus littéraire.

*En plein visage* laisse penser qu'il s'agissait d'un seul coup puissant.

Dans *frapper sur le visage*, plus rare que les autres, on peut penser qu'il y a plusieurs coups.

Les constructions sont aussi différentes :

> *Il l'ont frappé au visage.* (pas *le*)
> *Il lui ont frappé le visage.* (pas *au*)
> *La flèche l'a frappé en plein visage.*

Comment: "Frapper sur" me semble décrire un coup donné par un mouvement de haut en bas, ce qui expliquerait pourquoi ce n'est pas courant pour des coups portés au visage. On peut bien dire par contre "frapper sur la tête" ou "frapper sur le crâne ".

Comment: Pour moi « frapper sur le visage » est un anglicisme. *He hit me on the face* qui se dit en français « Il m'a frappé au visage ». Quid de gifler ? *Dans* me semble impossible sauf si le visage fait partie d'un tout  accroché au mur (photo de la personne) et que les coups sont portés sur le visage !

Comment: @None *Frapper sur le visage* n'est probablement pas un "pur" anglicisme, car on en trouve dès le XVIe siècle, mais que son usage ait été amplifié par l'anglais, c'est bien possible.

Comment: _Tu as déjà montré qu'elles_ --- Mais il n'est pas nécessaire d'ajouter _contre le mur_, ce n'était qu'un exemple. Il est possible de dire tout court _frapper le visage_. // @None Merci

Comment: @None  Une chose c'est des anglicismes au Canada, une autre seraient des anglicismes en France. Les bonnets sont très différents. //[frapper sur les fesses, pas sur ou au visage]

Comment: Oreste, ce que je voulais dire, c'est qu'il n'est pas possible de dire *frapper au visage contre un mur*.

Comment: @Lambie Quels bonnets ??

Comment: C'est une blague. Bonnet blanc, blanc bonnet.

Comment: @jlliagreJ'ai dit « pour moi » quand j'entends  « frapper sur le visage » en fait ça se transforme automatiquement en *hit me on the face*, c'est juste un truc que moi je ne peux pas dire en français ! Y'en a d'autres.

Comment: @Lambie Ah oui en français on me frapperait effectivement sur les fesses! (*but I'll never be given a good spanking*).

Comment: We generally say: hit someone in the face, not on the face.